# Unable to get INSendPaymentIntent work with SiriKit on watchOS (3.2 and 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos-3, watchos-4

I need to finish watchOS sirikit payment app (as a companion app for the iPhone app obviously). 
***The same framework, logic for intent and handler are working on iOS.***

I developed the intent and handler. When I ask Siri the below sentence,

```
using MyApp send Albert $40
```

Siri replies...

```
Sorry I can't do that. and give a button Open MyApp
```

I saw some posts saying Payment Intent for Siri is not available on watchOS. But I see this in SDK.
Please give pointers.

```
@available(watchOS 3.2, *)  
open class INSendPaymentIntent : INIntent {  
    public init(payee: INPerson?, currencyAmount: INCurrencyAmount?, note: String?)  
    @NSCopying open var payee: INPerson? { get }  
    @NSCopying open var currencyAmount: INCurrencyAmount? { get }  
    open var note: String? { get }  
}
```

The Plists and projects have right permissions and capabilities. 
Payment Intent Plist has the below keys.
[Image Link for Plist Keys for Payment Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMrNj.jpg)

```
// WatchIntentsExtension.swift
import Intents
import PaymentsFrameworkWatchOS

class WatchIntentsExtension: INExtension {
    let paymentProvider = PaymentProvider()
    let contactLookup = ContactLookup()

    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any? {
        print("Watch Overriding")
        guard intent is INSendPaymentIntent else { fatalError("Unhandled intent type \(intent)") }

        return WatchSendPaymentIntentHandler(paymentProvider: paymentProvider, contactLookup: contactLookup)
    }
}
```

I cannot post code for `Handler` as I have compliance issues. And... I do not do much on there. 
The same code works for iPhone Siri though.